# Creating unique id in mongodb which increments for each insert

Tags: mongodb, indexing

How can I create a unique index for my mongodb collection that will be incremented for each insert into the collection? I want to do it from my mongodb, not using mongoose. Is there any possible way ?

Answer (score 0):

Each driver provides an ObjectId generator which creates unique ids.

No driver can generate sequential integers in a globally unique manner, hence this isn't something that is provided. If you want this functionality you need to implement it yourself.